# Avoiding Multiple matches in regex

Tags: python, regex

This is the html code:

```
 [{file: "http://srv74.vidzi.tv/hls2/jjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgr,llnmsfgxyea6jqrfama,bb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa,.urlset/master.m3u8"},{file: "http://srv74.vidzi.tv/jjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgrbb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa/v.mp4"}]
```

My intention is to extract the link ending with v.mp4

My regex is as follows:

```
(http://srv74.vidzi.tv/.+?/v.mp4)
```

However, I get both urls as matches in my regex
How do I avoid multiple matches?

I am using [pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2F.%2B%3F%2Fv.mp4)&test_string=%20%5B%7Bfile%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2Fhls2%2Fjjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgr%2Cllnmsfgxyea6jqrfama%2Cbb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa%2C.urlset%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%2C%7Bfile%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2Fjjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgrbb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa%2Fv.mp4%22%7D%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Use: [`http://srv74.vidzi.tv/[^"]+/v\.mp4`](http://pythex.org/?regex=http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2F%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%2Fv.mp4&test_string=%20%5B%7Bfile%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2Fhls2%2Fjjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgr%2Cllnmsfgxyea6jqrfama%2Cbb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa%2C.urlset%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%2C%7Bfile%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fsrv74.vidzi.tv%2Fjjuqjoa4ki2qedz7nlhbttjfjz62mrdkpxryo6zgrbb5msfgxyencp5qkgqa%2Fv.mp4%22%7D%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: It works. But why should i use double-quote?

Comment: Because you are parsing a mark-up language, the text you want to get is inside double quotes. A negated character class prevent overflowing to another double quoted string.

Comment: Is it just me or is your "HTML" code actually JSON-esque?

Comment: @EyuelDK That is contained within the javascript.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks `"(http://srv74.vidzi.tv/.+?/v.mp4)"`But this does not work

Comment: [With `[^"]`, it works](https://regex101.com/r/ElPi4Z/1).

Comment: `"(http://srv74.vidzi.tv/.+?/v.mp4)"` won't work because `"http://srv74.vidzi.tv/` is common in both matches. `.+?/v\.mp4"` will match until it finds the given pattern hence matching across the URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get around using a common start position unless you exclude
it when using the dot `.` character.

This is the more reliable way.
Doing this you don't have to worry about valid url chars or
whether there are possibly other separators.

`(http://srv74\.vidzi\.tv/(?:(?!srv74\.vidzi\.tv).)+?/v\.mp4)`

https://regex101.com/r/xrnuZw/1

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      http://srv74\.vidzi\.tv/
      (?:
           (?! srv74\.vidzi\.tv )        # Don't let this be before mp4
           . 
      )+?
      /v \. mp4 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: This is a bit ugly. I prefer anubhava's answer in the comments.